# Dynamically edit value

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm try to play a bit with d3.js and kind of loving it for the moment :)

One thing I can't figure out is how edit same value one the fly. Let me explain, here is a simple donut :

```
var visu = d3.select("#svg_donut");
var skillScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2*Math.PI]);
var arcBorder = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(60)
                      .outerRadius(62)
                      .startAngle(0);
var arcBar = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(60)
                           .outerRadius(70)
                           .startAngle(0);
var progBorder = visu.append("path").datum({endAngle: skillScale(100)})
                             .style("fill", "white")
                             .attr("d", arcBorder)
                             .attr("transform", "translate(75, 75)");
var progBar = visu.append("path").datum({endAngle: skillScale(75)})
                                  .style("fill", "white")
                                  .attr("d", arcBar)
                                  .attr("transform", "translate(75, 75)");
var text = visu.append("text").text("FOO")
                             .attr("transform", "translate(75, 83)")
                             .style("fill", "white")
                             .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

And what I'ld like to do is, on the `hover` of `visu`, smoothly changing the `outerRadius` of `progbar`. I'm kind of stuck on it for the moment, so if you can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, this would actually be a bit tricky because you're drawing the donut in two separate parts. The general pattern would be something like this.

```
visu.on("mouseover", function() {
  arcBorder.outerRadius(100);
  visu.selectAll("path.outer").transition().attr("d", arcBorder);
});
```

This assumes that you have assigned the class "outer" to the path you want to change to be able to distinguish between this one and the others.

The whole thing is much easier if you use the more common pattern for donut charts, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/499/) for an example.

Comment: The second donut is just here for decoration, it can works without it. Just curious, if you remove the `arcBorder` and `progBorder`, what's weird with my way of drawing it ?

Comment: I'm really just having a hard time visualizing what your code would produce. I thought that you were combining both donuts in some way. If you're not, that certainly makes things much easier :)

Comment: Here is the result http://i.imgur.com/EQb0XMa.png, the second arc is just for decoration (I know, a simple circle would work too :) )

Comment: Ok, so then replace `arcBorder` in my answer with `arcBar`. The jsfiddle should also show you the general pattern :)

Comment: Ok ok, I'll look at your solution and at the jsfiddle too. Thank you :)